# Angular - Display message on specific item in a Loop

Tags: angular

I have a list of rows using For Loop. Clicking on any row, pops up a modal window. The modal window contains a Cancel and Ok button. When clicked on OK button, a message should appear on the ROW which was clicked.
Currently I can get the index number of the row and the message is showing on ALL rows when clicked OK. How can I display the message only on that specific ROW.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
```

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <span (click)="showModalWindow">
            <img class="actionIcon" src="images/action.png" />
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="ietm-img" *ngIf="item.image">
            <img [src]="item.image" alt="item" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="text">
            <h6>{{item.name}}</h6>
            <p>MESSAGE NEEDS TO APPEAR ONLY ON THE SELECTED ROW</p>
            <span>{{item.measurement}} {{item.length}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data appears to be coming from an API you may not have the ability to add an additional property to track the selected state of the row.

Consider capturing the selected row when the row is clicked, like so,

```
<span (click)="showModalWindow(); selectedRow=i" style="border:1px solid red">
```

Then you can set the hidden state when the row is clicked,

```
<p [hidden]="selectedRow !== i">MESSAGE NEEDS TO APPEAR ONLY ON THE SELECTED ROW</p>
```

In your component you'll need a variable to capture the state

```
selectedRow: Number;`
```

The completed template would look something like this:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
          <span (click)="showModalWindow(); selectedRow=i" style="border:1px solid red">
              <img class="actionIcon" src="images/action.png" />
          </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="ietm-img" *ngIf="item.image">
        <img [src]="item.image" alt="item" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="text">
        <h6>{{item.name}}</h6>
        <p [hidden]="selectedRow !== i">MESSAGE NEEDS TO APPEAR ONLY ON THE SELECTED ROW</p>
        <span>{{item.measurement}} {{item.length}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are close, the message is displaying on the selected Row, but clicking on Cancel button also displays the message, where I'm missing...

Comment: Could you share show you're launching the modal dialog?  A possible option would be to subscribe to the onClose (user clicks OK), return the index, and then set selectedRow to the index.

Comment: Did you mean this code:

`<span (click)="showModalWindow(); selectedRow=i" style="border:1px solid red">
              <img class="actionIcon" src="images/action.png" />
          </span>`

Comment: Yes,  You had this, (click)="showModalWindow" but I changed it to this (click)="showModalWindow();" assuming you're calling a function to display the modal.  You may need to return a value from the modal or share data from the modal when the OK button is clicked.  I'd like to know more about how you're launching the modal and the technology for the modal. Perhaps you can share some of that modal code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are multiple ways to do it. One way would be to introduce an additional boolean property (eg. `clicked`) in the `items` array of objects.

```
items = [
  {
    'name': 'sample',
    'measurement': 'sample',
    'clicked': false,
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

And set that property to `true` when the `OK` button is clicked in the modal. Now you could check this property using `*ngIf` in the template to display the message.

Template

```html
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="text">
    <h6>{{item.name}}</h6>
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.clicked">      <!-- check condition -->
      <p>MESSAGE NEEDS TO APPEAR ONLY ON THE SELECTED ROW</p>
    </ng-container>
    <span>{{item.measurement}} {{item.length}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Update: add `clicked` property

You could introduce the `clicked` property to the data obtained from the API before assigning it to the `items` variable.

```js
this.apiService.getItems().pipe(
  map(items => items.map(item => ({ ...item, clicked: false });
).subscribe(
  items => { this.items = items },
  error => { }
);
```

Now there is property called `clicked` in each object of the array. Set it to `false` if an object is opened in the template and the OK button is clicked in the modal.

Comment: What if data is coming from an API

Comment: Yes that is why I mentioned to *introduce* a new property to each object of the array.

Comment: Sorry, not getting the point. You have mentioned to add new property in the object, but I don't have that object in my file, where do I add that property now.